# How to do multi-column sorting on a Visual Basic 6 ListView?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sorting

I am working in Visual Basic 6 and need to sort by multiple columns in a ListView.  For example, sorting a list of music tracks by artist, then album, then track number.  As far as I know, VB6 does not support this out of the box.  Here are the suggestions I have already heard:

- Sort the data in a SQL table first and display the data in the resulting order
- Sort the data in an ADO recordset object in memory
- Sort by the primary column and then perform a sort algorithm on the items, moving them around into the correct positions manually

Does anyone have experience with multiple-column sorting in VB6 who could lend advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a hidden column in the listview that concatenates those three columns and sort by that

Answer (score 1):

You can try sorting using the Windows API and callbacks: [Link](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/callback/lvsortcallback.htm)

Alternatively, you could try switching to a [vbAccelerator ListView](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/ListView/article.asp); I highly recommend it.